# Magento UNION SQL

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm using Magento and I have problem with using sql command UNION with my collections. I have two collections:

```
       $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->joinRight(
        array('sfi' => 'sales_flat_invoice'),
        'main_table.entity_id = sfi.order_id AND
        NOW()<= DATE_ADD(main_table.created_at, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)',
        array()
    );
    $collection->getselect()->joinLeft(
        array('ztr'=>'zdg_tv_report'),
        'ztr.type=\'TV\' AND ztr.number=main_table.increment_id',
        array('*')
    );
    $collection->addFieldToSelect(new Zend_Db_Expr('main_table.increment_id'));
```

and

```
$collection2 = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $collection2->getSelect()->joinRight(
        array('sfc'=>'sales_flat_creditmemo'),
        'main_table.entity_id= sfc.order_id AND
        NOW()<= DATE_ADD(main_table.created_at, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)',
        array()
        );
        $collection2->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('ztr'=>'zdg_tv_report'),
            'ztr.type=\'Reverse_TV\' AND ztr.number=main_table.increment_id',
            array('*')
        );
    $collection2->addFieldToSelect(new Zend_Db_Expr('main_table.increment_id'));
```

I tried to use

```
$collection->getSelect()->union(array($collection2->getSelect()));
```

but SQL select I got seems to be completely messed up:

```
SELECT main_table.increment_id, `ztr`.*SELECT main_table.increment_id, `ztr`.* FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` RIGHT JOIN `sales_flat_creditmemo` AS `sfc` ON main_table.entity_id= sfc.order_id AND NOW()<= DATE_ADD(main_table.created_at, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) LEFT JOIN `zdg_tv_report` AS `ztr` ON ztr.type='Reverse_TV' AND ztr.number=main_table.increment_id FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` RIGHT JOIN `sales_flat_invoice` AS `sfi` ON main_table.entity_id = sfi.order_id AND NOW()<= DATE_ADD(main_table.created_at, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) LEFT JOIN `zdg_tv_report` AS `ztr` ON ztr.type='TV' AND ztr.number=main_table.increment_idSELECT main_table.increment_id, `ztr`.*SELECT main_table.increment_id, `ztr`.* FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` RIGHT JOIN `sales_flat_creditmemo` AS `sfc` ON main_table.entity_id= sfc.order_id AND NOW()<= DATE_ADD(main_table.created_at, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) LEFT JOIN `zdg_tv_report` AS `ztr` ON ztr.type='Reverse_TV' AND ztr.number=main_table.increment_id FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` RIGHT JOIN `sales_flat_invoice` AS `sfi` ON main_table.entity_id = sfi.order_id AND NOW()<= DATE_ADD(main_table.created_at, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) LEFT JOIN `zdg_tv_report` AS `ztr` ON ztr.type='TV' AND ztr.number=main_table.increment_id
```

I also tried to use

```
    $unionSelect = new Varien_Db_Select();
    $unionSelect->union(array($collection->getSelect(), $collection2->getSelect()));
```

but then I don't know how to put such select into collection. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can try use the following variant to perform the UNION statement within Magento:

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

 $select1 = clone $collection->getSelect();
 $select1->joinRight...

 $select2 = clone $collection->getSelect();
 $select2->joinRight...

 $collection->getSelect()->reset();
 $collection->getSelect()->union(array($select1, $select2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite get Alexey's method to work as-is, but this worked for me:

```
$selectOne = clone $this;
$selectOne->addFieldToFilter(...);
$selectOne->addFieldToFilter(...);
$selectOne->getSelect()->limit(...);
$selectOneSql = $selectOne->getSelect()->__toString();

$selectTwo = clone $this;
$selectTwo->getSelect()->setPart('where', null);
$selectTwo->addFieldToFilter(...);
$selectTwo->addFieldToFilter(...);
$selectTwo->getSelect()->limit(...);
$selectTwoSql = $selectTwo->getSelect()->__toString();

$this->getSelect()->reset();
$this->getSelect()->union(array(
    new Zend_Db_Expr($selectOneSql),
    new Zend_Db_Expr($selectTwoSql),
));
```

From what I can tell, most or all of the places where `->union()` are used in the Magento core, the method is passed strings or `Zend_Db_Expr` objects.